# IE9 Issue With Float: Right and Margin-Top For My Search Widget Submit Button

Tags: search, widget, internet-explorer-9

In Chrome, the website bmr1.com shows the search widget with a magnifying glass as the submit buttons background image. In order to get the submit button to move I added Float:Right and Margin-top, to get it into the correct position. I also had to add position:relative, so that the button would be positioned on top of the text box. Issue is the same margin-top: of 31px that fixes Chrome, makes IE9's submit button way too high and out of place.

```
bmr1.com

<div id="search-2" class="widget widget_search"><h4 class="widgettitle"><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Search" style="width: 64px; height: 22px; "><canvas width="80" height="28" style="width: 80px; height: 28px; top: -4px; left: -1px; "></canvas><cufontext>Search</cufontext></cufon></h4><form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://bmr1.com/">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="" widdit="on" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="">
    </form><div id="predictad_div" class="predictad"></div></div>


#sidebar1 { position: relative; }
#search-2.widget.widget_search {z-index:0; background-color: #363636; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom:25px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; color:#363636; max-width:231px;}
#search-2.widget.widget_search #s{width:94%; padding: 5px;position:relative;}
#search-2.widget.widget_search h4  {font-size:140%; background-color: #84c4e7; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #fff; margin-bottom:10px;}
.widget_search .screen-reader-text {margin-bottom:-20px;float:right;}
#mp_cart_widget-3.widget.mp_cart_widget { background-color: #cdcdcd; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom:25px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; max-width:231px;}
#mp_cart_widget-3.widget.mp_cart_widget h4  { font-size:140%; background-image:url('http://technickconsulting.com/testblog/wp-content/themes/BoatMotorRecyclers/images/greysliver.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x; padding: 5px 10px 6px 10px; margin-bottom:10px; color:#fff; }
#mp_categories_widget-3.widget.mp_categories_widget { background-color: #363636; margin-right:15px; margin-bottom:20px; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; color:#fff; max-width:231px;}
#mp_categories_widget-3.widget.mp_categories_widget h4 { font-size:140%; background-color: #84c4e7; padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #fff; margin-bottom:10px; color:#363636;}
#mp_categories_widget-3.widget.mp_categories_widget a {text-decoration:none; color:#fff; margin-left: 30px; }
#sidebar ul {font-size:18px;  font-weight:bold; }
ul#mp_category_list {padding-right:10px;font-size:18px; }
ul#mp_category_list .children {text-align:left;list-style: none;margin-left:10px; font-size:15px !important;}
.widget_search #searchsubmit {
background-image:url('http://technickconsulting.com/testblog/wp-content/themes/BoatMotorRecyclers/images/magglass.png');
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color:transparent;
height: 28px;
width:30px;
cursor: pointer;
float:right;
padding: 8px 16px;
margin-top:-31px;
position:relative;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.widget_search #searchsubmit {
background-image: url('http://technickconsulting.com/testblog/wp-content/themes/BoatMotorRecyclers/images/magglass.png');
background-color: transparent;
border: none;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 28px;
width: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
top: 3px;
right: 0;
}

#search-2 form {position: relative;}
```

Also, I highly recommend to use a css reset! This will make every slight difference in lay-out between browsers go away. You will need to overwrite some of these values, but it saves you a lot of frustration in the long run!

An example: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous commenter, use a reset.css! Different browsers has different default margin, padding etc values for everything and it makes your webpage look different in each of them.

To fix the problem you should do the followings.
First, give a fixed height for your text input field:

```
#search-2.widget.widget_search #s{width:94%;height:20px; padding: 5px;position:relative;}
```

*Change is that I have applied a 20 pixel height for the element*

Then apply the following to the submit button:

```
.widget_search #searchsubmit {
background-image:url('http://technickconsulting.com/testblog/wp-content/themes/BoatMotorRecyclers/images/magglass.png');
background-color:transparent;
border:none;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color:transparent;
height: 28px;
width:30px;
cursor: pointer;
float:right;
bottom:31px;
position:relative;
  }
```

*You should use shortcodes like background: url('http://technickconsulting.com/testblog/wp-content/themes/BoatMotorRecyclers/images/magglass.png') no-repeat; to make your code shorter and cleaner*

I hope this will fix your issue.